# How to get parameters of cron job Schedule in laravel

Tags: parameters, cron, jobs, schedule, laravel-5.1

When I run  `crontab -e`

```
* * * * * php /srv/PHP/devloper/test/artisan schedule:run company-cd=1
```

In Kernel.php , I have functiom
protected function `schedule(Schedule $schedule)`

```
 {    
        $schedule->command('test:alertlimitedstock --company-cd=1') 
                ->withoutOverlapping() 
                ->cron('* * * * *');          
    }
```

How to get company from cron command?